# Calculating hyperbolic length

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

So, I am looking at a question and I'm having a hard time solving it.

[image]

So I know the formula but my question is first, what is $\alpha$ and what is $\beta$?

So I calculated some values:

I found $AC=CB=\sqrt{(1-(-1))^2+(1-0)^2}=\sqrt{5}$

and I found $AB=\sqrt{(0-1)^2+(2-1)^2}=\sqrt{2}$.

Let take $\csc{\alpha}$. Well i know $\csc{\alpha}$ is the same as $\frac{1}{\sin(\alpha)}$

but the truth is, I really do not know to understand this question since I do not know what $\alpha$ and what is $\beta$?

If anyone can help me, I think I can progress from there.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are points in the hyperbolic plane, then it does not make sense to calculate the distance by the 'euclidean distance'. The distance of two points in the hyperbolic plane is given by $\mathrm{dist}(A,B) = \arccos (-\langle A, B \rangle)$ .Also for $AC$ and $CB$. 

To answer your question. $\alpha$ is the angle between the triangle $\hat{ACO}$ and $\beta$ the angle between $\hat{BCO}$. So take a pencil and connect $A$ and $O$ und also connect $B$ and $O$.

Comment: @aGer. thanks i shall work it out now and see if i get the answer.